# Bosh multiple streams with strophe as a client

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am trying to build a group chat application by using Bosh over XMPP and stophe as a client. I am very new to Bosh and I have following questions

1) Does stophe support bosh multiple streams out of the box?
2) For every user, there would be a one bosh session with their own stream ? or for one chat session there will be one bosh session with multiple streams ?
Example: I have user1, user2 and user3 who are part of chat session. So there will be one bosh session for chat session which will be shared by all the users or every user will have their own bosh session

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score -1):

```
I strongly recommend you this book: 
Professional XMPP Programming with Javascript and JQuery - Jack Moffitt

And in special this chapter: 
Chapter 8  Group Chatting: A Multi‑User Chat Client......165

I'm sure that all the answers for all your questions are there.

I'm building single chat an application javascript+strophejs just reading this book.

Good luck.
```